# Pandas, selecting rows with conditions depend on column date value

Tags: python, pandas

I begin with my dataframe:

```
ID Alarm          Date
1   1    2017-09-06 13:41:36.0
1   2    2017-09-06 15:50:20.0
2   3    2016-12-12 13:30:30.0
2   1    2017-09-03 18:24:12.0
2   2    2017-09-06 12:01:51.0
3   4    2017-08-10 13:11:11.0
3   2    2017-09-06 14:43:33.0
```

So for each ID it is sorted ascending by Date. Now I would like to select only rows, which have date maximum one week earlier than the date from the last record in each ID (it is always with Alarm = 2). It should be done for each ID separately. The output should look like this:

```
ID Alarm          Date
1   1    2017-09-06 13:41:36.0
1   2    2017-09-06 15:50:20.0
2   1    2017-09-03 18:24:12.0
2   2    2017-09-06 12:01:51.0
3   2    2017-09-06 14:43:33.0
```

I tried grouping by ID, but I don't know how to connect Alarms and Dates. What is the simplest way to it, maybe something with external 'time' libraries?

Comment: It's a little unclear on how you want to filter your data. Do you want to output the last week of each unique ID?  
Could you also give a little more detail on the dataframe (`df.info()`)

Comment: Yes last week, but from date with Alarm=2 for each ID. It is only my local example, so giving df.info could be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with filtering by compare subtracted last day with `Timedelta`:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x >= x.iat[-1] - pd.Timedelta(7, unit='d')))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool

df = df[df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x >= x.iat[-1] - pd.Timedelta(7, unit='d'))]
print (df)
   ID  Alarm                Date
0   1      1 2017-09-06 13:41:36
1   1      2 2017-09-06 15:50:20
3   2      1 2017-09-03 18:24:12
4   2      2 2017-09-06 12:01:51
6   3      2 2017-09-06 14:43:33
```